# Come tradurre: Quota?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, translation

Buongiorno!

Come posso tradurre **Quota** dall'inglese all'italiano?

Il contesto è l'organizzazione di eventi.

Come parola singola l'ho tradotta sin qui come **totale**. Può andare?

Ma come posso tradurre **Remaining quota**?

**Totale rimanente** non mi convince..

**Quota rimanente** si capisce?

Si intende ad esempio il totale di stanze messe a disposizione da un hotel.
Oppure il totale dei posti a disposizione per il transfer dall'aeroporto ecc..

Grazie!

Comment: Johnny, quando avrai finito compili da qualche parte un bel glossario per mettere insieme tutte le soluzioni che hai trovato (per conto tuo o qui)?

Comment: Va bene :) Posso fare un glossario di termini inerenti all'organizzazione di eventi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nelle accezioni indicate da te, quali stanze in hotel e posti sui mezzi per il trasferimento in aeroporto, userei il termine ***disponibilità residua***, visto che è una grandezza che tende ad esaurirsi nel tempo.

Il senso è: quanti posti sono ancora disponibili (oppure liberi)?

Concordo con te su ***Totale rimanente***.

***Quota rimanente*** potrebbe anche andare bene, ma in quel contesto mi risulterebbe un po' forzato.

Comment: "Disponibilità residua" o "Disponibilità" secondo me sono corretti.